# ISO8601DateFormatter not converting a string to date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, iso8601

I have this datetime string **2020-03-09T11:53:39.474Z**. I need to convert it to a `Date`

```
let dateString = "2020-03-09T11:53:39.474Z"
if let date = ISO8601DateFormatter().date(from: dateString) {
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
} else {
    print("Could not convert date")
}
```

But it fails to convert it properly.

Any idea why this it's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [designated initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/1643114-init) `init()` of `ISO8601DateFormatter` does this:

> By default, a formatter is initialized to use the GMT time zone, the RFC 3339 standard format ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"), and the following options: `withInternetDateTime`, `withDashSeparatorInDate`, `withColonSeparatorInTime`, and `withTimeZone`.

Obviously, your date is not in the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`, because it has a milliseconds component.

You just need to add the `withFractionalSeconds` option:

```
let dateString = "2020-03-09T11:53:39.474Z"
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
formatter.formatOptions = [
    .withInternetDateTime, 
    .withFractionalSeconds, 
    .withColonSeparatorInTime, 
    .withDashSeparatorInDate, 
    .withTimeZone]
if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(date)
} else {
    print("Could not convert date")
}
```

I personally like to list the options all out to make the code clearer, but you can also do:

```
formatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)
```